# How to read the data from the file get a link to it from the front?

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I use angular 7 on the front end, send several text fields and one field is responsible for the file. To add a file, I take a link to this file on the front, it looks something like C: \ fakepath \ test.txt, I need to get this link on the backend and take this file from it and add it to the project file system, and then read the data From this file and return to the front the entire content of this file, I tried several options, did not work.
My service method:

```
 public void save(Accounting accounting) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File(accounting.getFile());
    String contents = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    accounting.setFile(contents);
    accountingRepository.save(accounting);
}
```

My controller  method

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping({"/createAccounting"})
public Accounting create(@RequestBody Accounting accounting) throws FileNotFoundException {
    accountingService.save(accounting);
    return accounting;
}
```

the link comes to bachend, stored in the file field

Comment: did you tried multipart file upload? It will help to get the file but not the path, as path is blocked now a days for security reason, SO, send your data as POST and multipart file.

Comment: I have not used it, maybe you have an example?

Comment: Sure I will add it give me some time to recreate it for you.